# Set jQuery Flot bar color through css?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, controller, flot

I am making use of jQuery flot library in Angular JS. The graph is drawn in my case in the controller. So it is here where the color is also set.

Is there a way to set the color of the bar through css?

Comment: What have you already came up with

Comment: Like i mentioned, bar graphs done in controller and color also set there. I want to set the color, or override the color through css

Comment: You cannot do this because the bars are not DOM elements but are part of a drawn canvas. The only why to change the colors of the bars is to draw a new chart with the other colors.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so!

Comment: But one quick question, if they are not DOM elements, how am I able to change the width, height through css?

Comment: You are not. You can only change the width and height of the complete canvas.